# NixOS: Install unfree package using different channel

Tags: nix, nixos

I am using the default nixos 17.09 channel and want to install an `unfree` package from the unstable channel.

I am using `(import <nixos-unstable> {}).vscode`  to install vscode in this case, but I am getting the error that I must set `...allowUnfree = true;`
It seems that the setting only applies to the default channel.
How can I set `allowFree = true;` also on the unstable channel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution (https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/25880#issuecomment-322855573).

It creates an alias for the unstable channel with the same config.

```
nixpkgs.config = 
{
    # Allow proprietary packages
    allowUnfree = true;

    # Create an alias for the unstable channel
    packageOverrides = pkgs: 
    {
        unstable = import <nixos-unstable> 
            { 
                # pass the nixpkgs config to the unstable alias
                # to ensure `allowUnfree = true;` is propagated:
                config = config.nixpkgs.config; 
            };
    };
};
```

Then you can use it like `unstable.vscode` instead of `(import <nixos-unstable> {}).vscode`.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative example:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

let
  unstable = import <unstable> {
    config = config.nixpkgs.config; 
  };
in
{
   environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
     # google-chrome
     unstable.google-chrome
   ];

    nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true;
}
```